# If string contains substring get that substring

Tags: swift

Im getting a string like this from a barcode reader how can I check to see if the string has a substring say for example DCS and store that substring into a var?
something like

`if string contains "DCS"
   let tmpString = substring["DCS"]`

DCBNONE
DCDNONE
DBA02172021
DCSPHANFIELD
DACMIKE
DADJOE
DBB09171988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really unclear. I think what you meant was "if the barcode has a word that contains the string DSC, get that word". If so, split the barcode string by space:

```
let barcode = "DCBNONE DCDNONE DBA02172021 DCSPHANFIELD DACMIKE DADJOE DBB09171988"

// This is an array containing all words that has "DCS" inside it
let words = barcode.components(separatedBy: " ").filter { $0.contains("DCS") }
```

Answer (score 0):

something like so

```
   let x = "adfsads"
    if x.contains("adf"){
        var y = x
        print(y)
    }
```